# Is there a way to log filenames in release build using timber for android?

Tags: android, logging, android-r8, timber-android

I just started using timber for logging on android, we are trying to add filenames/class-names to log message. I was able to add filenames in debug build using debug tree, but I'm not finding a way to add filenames in the release tree. Is there a possibility to add the filename in the release tree with R8 enabled?

Comment: What kind of the filenames do you mean? Can you make it clear please?

Comment: @HalilSahin class names/filenames

Answer (score 0):

Okay use it like this:
Define a TAG variable with your class name in your whole classes as:

```
private static final String TAG = "Your class name";
```

then pass your TAG:

```
Timber.tag(TAG).d("Error %s!", error);
```

Comment: sorry, I cannot accept this answer, I'm trying to find a way without using tags.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace) there are several ways to go about this.

#### For release builds

When you generate an actual release build of the app that you intend to publish on the Play Store you also get a `mapping.txt` for every release artifact. Upload this file (be careful - every build generates a new file, so you must use the exact file that was generated with your artifact) and Google will deobfuscate crash logs in the Google Play Console for you.

You also have the option to use the `retrace` command line tool to translate logs you receive from this build yourself using `mapping.txt`.

#### For non-release builds/internal testing

Since you will not be releasing this artifact to the world it is possibly acceptable to break your own code obfuscation. You can use rules in the `proguard-rules.pro` file to keep relevant information during R8 shrinking.

Check [the docs](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage) for all relevant parameters. Especially useful are
`-dontobfuscate`, `-keeppackagenames` and `-keepattributes` (with params like `SourceFile` and `LineNumberTable`).

Remember that changes in shrinking and obfuscating code can break thinks like reflection and resource lookup when you do these manually. So make sure your obfuscated release build works as expected after fiddling with these parameters.

Comment: my question is 'how to find the class-name/filename', not 'how to find the obfuscated class-name'

Comment: As you may have read in my answer you would either do so by using Google Play or the `retrace` tool with the mapping.txt file or by omitting obfuscation entirely. Which step do you have trouble with?